# Почему после Ajax отваливается JavaScript код и как с этим бороться?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Банальный пример: [Bootstrap Tooltips](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips)

Представим некий список, где есть tooltip. Как только мы загрузили страницу, все tooltips в этом списке рабочие. Ах да, еще у нас в `<head>` страницы подключен файл с этим кодом:

```
$(function () {
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
})
```

Теперь добавим элемент-дубликат в этот список с помощью Ajax. Не важно как именно реализуется Ajax запрос - итог один.

У нового элемента не будет работать tooltip. Я исправляю ситуацию следующим образом: вместе с html кодом (в данном примере - html кодом элемента списка) я отправляю еще и это:

```
<script>$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();</script>
```

Добавили 10 элементов в список, собрали под ним 10 одинаковых строк `script`. Зато все работает.

Но появилась необходимость реализовать функционал далеко не просто списка. Сейчас имею множество компонентов на странице, каждый из которых работает на Ajax - пагинация, тот же список с элементами, в котором еще что-то с Ajax. Все в таком духе.

И "лечить" это так, как я это описал выше - невозможно.

Неужели нет нормального способа взаимодействия "новых элементов из ajax" с JS средой страницы?

Comment: зачем отправлять разметку `<script>$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();</script>` если вызвать эту функцию можно самому сразу после непосредственного получения?

Comment: Поздравляю, теперь вы знаете почему опытные разработчики ненавидят "магические" jquery-плагины.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, кстати, вроде бы, в jquery-ui Не надо каждый раз инициализировать

Comment: @Grundy любой динамически созданный элемент нуждается в инициализации

Comment: @PavelMayorov, Не, там один раз событие навешивается и все

Comment: @Grundy на куда оно там навешивается?

Comment: @PavelMayorov, а не помню. на документ, а событие какое-нибудь mouseenter

Comment: @Grundy а как без отправки разметки? Я пытался инициализировать после append, но безрезультатно.

Comment: @Colibri, очевидно ты что-то делал неверно

Comment: @Grundy ну я не знаю, опишите подробнее, что я должен сделать. Я не прошу у вас готовый код :) Прост объясните поподробнее, пожалуйста.

Comment: @Colibri имеется ввиду, что вы вроде пишете _"...реализуется Ajax запрос..."_ ну вот там где он _реализуется_ и вызывайте `.tooltip()`.

Comment: @AlexanderIgorevich тогда я все верно понял в тот раз. Не помогает это.

Comment: @Colibri Дополните вопрос куском кода, где вы _"пытался инициализировать после append"_. Очевидно, что ответ кроется именно там.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('body').tooltip({
    selector: '[data-toggle="tooltip"]'
});
```

Согласно документации будет работать для динамически добавленых элементов.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Раз уж вы уловили суть и ваш ответ верный, то помогите (очень прошу) еще с этим вопросом. Знаю, возможно наглость, но тут сложнее ситуация. Та же самая проблема, только с http://intercoolerjs.org. Я не знаю как тут инициализировать библиотеку после Ajax. Проблема в том, что есть Ajax пагинация. И когда переходишь на новую страницу, то Intercooler полностью перестает работать.

Comment: Создал отдельный вопрос: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/626122/Почему-не-работает-intercooler-после-ajax-запроса