# Как использовать плагины jquery с динамическим контентом или почему после AJAX отваливается javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, javascript-faq

Подключил на страницу несколько суперплагинов:

```
$("*[data-foo]").foo();
$(".bar").bar();
$("p a b i").baz();
```

Но после загрузки через AJAX код перестает работать! Как это исправить?!

Comment: Это все конечно очень хорошо, и ответ полезен, но почему не в изначальном вопросе? :/

Comment: @SLy_huh которой из вопросов - изначальный? Они же постоянно появляются.

Comment: Возможно, [который](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/625732/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-ajax-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-javascript-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81-%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F) и сподвиг вас на это

Comment: @SLy_huh кроме того, все задаваемые вопросы, как правило, привязаны к конкретным плагинам, серверным языкам или CMS. Скажем, тот, который вы упомянули, привязан к Bootstrap Tooltips. Если дать ответ на него - нельзя будет делаеть его дубликатом вопрос, который этих самых Bootstrap Tooltips не касается.

Comment: Ну, бутстрап там в кач-ве примера, и только. Его ни в шапке, ни в тегах нет, общий смысл вопроса там как раз под ваш ответ. Я не прикапываюсь, просто как говорится, `just sayin'`

Comment: Мне не нравится формулировка «суперплагинов». Слишком свободная форма для каноничного ответа, пахнет язвительной усмешкой над теми, чей вопрос будет помечаться дубликатом. Предлагаю переписать.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Говорить, что "код перестает работать" - некорректно. Потому что код работать и *не начинал*. Когда вы пишите `$(селектор).метод()` - это означает *однократный* вызов метода. Этот метод применяется ко всем элементам, соответствующим переданному селектору, *которые в этот момент были на странице*.

Обычно говорят, что чтобы исправить ошибку, надо после обновления страницы через ajax выполнить код еще раз. Но это не всегда верно.

Повторное выполнение вызова вида `$(".bar").bar();` вызовет плагин `bar` не только на новых элементах - но и на старых. В лучшем случае будет бесполезно потраченное время. Но в худшем случае из-за повторного вызова что-нибудь поломается (а если вы подписывались на события - то что-нибудь поломается гарантировано!). Поэтому надо применять плагины только к обновленному контейнеру.

Также бывают грабли с тем, как вызывать эти плагины после обновления. Обычно это пытаются делать через инлайн script в ответе сервера - но в таком случае этот скрипт не имеет доступа к обновляемому элементу. Надо искать в коде где происходит само обновление - и править там.

---

Выше был общий принцип. Ниже я напишу способ, которым можно попытаться заставить заработать код в простом случае.

1. Собираем все "улучшения" страницы в одном месте:

   ```
   applyPlugins();

   // ...
   function applyPlugins() {
     $("*[data-foo]").foo();
     $(".bar").bar();
     $("p a b i").baz();
   }
   ```
2. Изменяем получившуюся функцию так, чтобы она действовала только внутри переданного ей контейнера:

   ```
   applyPlugins($(document));

   function applyPlugins($cnt) {
     $cnt.find("*[data-foo]").foo();
     $cnt.find(".bar").bar();
     $cnt.find("p a b i").baz();
   }
   ```

   Здесь мы воспользовались методом [`find`](https://api.jquery.com/find/), который ищет дочерние элементы.

   Важно! Функция `applyPlugins` не должна обращаться к элементам за пределами переданного ей контейнера `$cnt`!
3. Находим в коде те места, где выполняется динамическое обновление содержимого или создание элементов.

   Это может быть вызов [`.html(...)`](http://api.jquery.com/html/):

   ```
   $.ajax({
       // ...

       success: function (data) {
         $("#some_block").html(data);
       }
   });
   ```

   В таком случае надо после вызова `html` добавить вызов `applyPlugins`:

   ```
   $.ajax({
       // ...

       success: function (data) {
         applyPlugins($("#some_block").html(data));
       }
   });
   ```

   Это может быть вызов [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/):

   ```
   $("#some_block").load("http://some/url");
   ```

   В таком случае надо добавить туда параметр с функцией обратного вызова:

   ```
   $("#some_block").load("http://some/url", function () {
     applyPlugins($(this));
   });
   ```

   Это может быть и что-то другое. Но все же надеюсь что вы это место найдете - это же ваш код, а не чей-то еще :)

---

Способ выше не будет работать если используемый для плагина селектор проходит через динамический контейнер:

```
$(".foo .bar .baz").somePlugin();

$(".bar").load(...);
```

В таком случае попытка прямого переписывания в applyPlugins в виде `$cnt.find(".foo .bar .baz").somePlugin()` будет неудачной, поскольку ни `.foo`, ни `.bar` не являются дочерними элементами для обновляемого контейнера.

В таком случае вам, наверное, стоит более внимательно отнестись к тому что и как вы обновляете или загружаете вместо слепого применения трюка с applyPlugins.

Или же можно попытаться сделать как-то так, чтобы предусмотреть все случаи - но этот код для понимания и для отладки будет довольно тяжелым:

```
$cnt.find(".foo .bar .baz").somePlugin();
$cnt.filter(".foo, .foo *").find(".bar .baz").somePlugin();
$cnt.filter(".foo .bar, .foo .bar *").find(".baz").somePlugin();
```

(Здесь проверяется, является ли текущий контейнер элементом `.foo` или его дочерним элементом, и если является - в пути `.foo .bar .baz` пропускается первый элемент. Этот код предполагает, что один `.foo` не может быть вложен в другой. То же самое для `.bar`.)

---

PS хотя я говорил только про плагины, ответ можно применять и для подписки на события. Но это будет не самый лучший способ - потому что есть способ проще. Большинство событий является всплывающими - а потому их можно отлавливать в корне документа. И JQuery имеет встроенные механизмы для фильтрации всплывших событий. Пример:

```
$(document).on("click", "a[data-href]", function (e) {
    // ...
})
```

Этот обработчик будет слушать нажатия на любые ссылки с установленным атрибутом `data-href` независимо от того, как и когда они появились на странице.