# Раскрыть блок, который возвращается через Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Всем привет. Есть кнопка. При нажатии на которую на сервер через ajax идет запрос к данным.
Возвращаются вот так они

Потом когда вернулись данные на главную страничку откуда был отправлен запрос, мне нужно что бы при нажатии на .asc_block раскрывался блок .asc_slide которые следует за ним.

```html
<p class="tit font-weight-bold asc_block">
  <?=$tv?>
</p>
<div class="asc_slide">
  Тут ненужный код
</div>
<p class="tit font-weight-bold asc_block">
  <?=$tv?>
</p>
<div class="asc_slide">
  Тут ненужный код
</div>
<p class="tit font-weight-bold asc_block">
  <?=$tv?>
</p>
<div class="asc_slide">
  Тут ненужный код
</div>
```

Пишут хотя б вот так

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.asc_block').click(function() {
                   alert(1);
                });
});
```

Но кнопка те отрабатывает, что может быть? т.е. если б изначально была бы это кнопка в построени DOM то работает, а тут я жду ее через ajax, и не работает.

Comment: ну так может стоит поискать "ajax + динамические элементы", например?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как использовать плагины jquery с динамическим контентом или почему после AJAX отваливается javascript](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/625993/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%8b-jquery-%d1%81-%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-ajax-%d0%be)

Answer (score 0):

После того как через `ajax`-запрос получите в ответ кусок `html`-кода - добавьте его в `DOM` внутрь нужного блока (например в блок `.inside-block`)

```js
$ajax_loaded_html = '<p class="tit font-weight-bold asc_block">...</p>';
$('.inside-block').html( $ajax_loaded_html  );
```

И уже после этого навешивайте обработчик на элемент с классом `.asc-block`

```js
$('.asc_block').on('click', function(){
   ...
});
```

Почему так? Потому, что `DOM` до того как Вы добавили в него кусок `html` с нужными блоками просто-напросто о них ничего не знает так как нет элементов с такими классами и соответственно Ваш обработчик на `$(document).ready()` ни к чему не прикреплен. А вот после того как Вы добавили в `DOM` данные элементы вызов `js`-кода с обработкой уже будет навешан на конкретные элементы.

P.S Если у Вас планируется добавление таких элементов не один раз то лучше перед `$('.asc_block').on('click')` вызвать `$('.asc_block').unbind('click')` дабы у Вас не навешался обработчик избыточное кол-во раз.