# Не пойму почему не срабатывает инициализация плагина после AJAX

Tags: jquery, jquery-form

Не пойму в чем проблема, нужно через jQuery Form Styler стилизовать селекты, я запускаю:

```
 function runStyler() { 
$('select').each(function() { 
    if (!$(this).hasClass('active')) {
        $(this).addClass('active'); //чтобы при добавлении select через Ajax не инициализировать заново плагин
        console.log($(this))
        $(this).styler({
      selectSearch: true,
    });
    }
});
```

в итоге все работает при загрузке страницы, но как только срабатывает success у Ajax и я вызываю функцию runStyler() в консоли ошибка:

```
$(this).styler is not a function. (In '$(this).styler({
      selectSearch: true,
    })', '$(this).styler' is undefined
```

Как я понял тут много вопросов связанных с тем что после появления элементов с помощью Ajax не работают ранее вызванные плагины, так вот я вызываю инициализацию плагина для новых элементов и получаю непонятную для себя ошибку.

страница сайта с ошибкой: https://varmedia.ru/category/fitnes-mebel/ckamejki-dlja-razdevalok

файл index.js строка 354 и 371 (успешная загрузка товаров через ajax)

Помогите пожалуйста, уже всю голову сломал и не пойму в чем проблема.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как использовать плагины jquery с динамическим контентом или почему после AJAX отваливается javascript](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/625993/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%8b-jquery-%d1%81-%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-ajax-%d0%be)

Answer (score 0):

Как оказалось причина была в том что jquery вызывлась два раза в шапке сайта и в футере. Удалил лишнюю все заработало