# Почему не работает Intercooler после Ajax запроса?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Речь об [этой](http://intercoolerjs.org) библиотеке. Подключил ее. Теперь если на странице разместить этот код ссылки:

```
<a ic-post-to="/click">Link</a>
```

То он превратиться в это:

```
<a ic-post-to="/click" ic-src="/click" ic-verb="POST" ic-trigger-on="default" ic-deps="ignore" ic-id="7">Link</a>
```

Новые атрибуты - это нам говорит о том, что библиотека работает.

Теперь к сути вопроса. Похожая ссылка есть в HTML коде, который динамически подгружается на страницу. И суть в том, что в итоге в исходном коде страницы размещается точно такой же html код ссылки, что я и передаю из back-end'а. То есть вот эти все атрибуты в ссылке, которые подставляет библиотека для своей работы - их нет. Библиотека не работает. Да и по нажатии на ссылку ничего не уходит.

То есть, если говорить вкратце, то библиотека не инициализируется в этот момент.

Как исправить? Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Ну звучит достаточно просто - вам надо заного вызвать intercoolerjs чтобы он прошелся по html и заменил нужные блоки своими. Обычно это делают с помощью callback после ajax реквеста (который вернет вам еще не обработанный intercoolerjs html). Наверняка у этой либы есть метод, который запускает ее обработчик для определенного куска кода (сам не работал с ней, но по схожему принципу работают и другие либы-парсеры)

Comment: Как мне показалось, это Intercooler.refresh(eltOrPath) запрос или Intercooler.processNodes(elt)  (http://intercoolerjs.org/docs.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну звучит достаточно просто - вам надо заного вызвать intercoolerjs чтобы он прошелся по html и заменил нужные блоки своими. Обычно это делают с помощью callback после ajax реквеста (который вернет вам еще не обработанный intercoolerjs html). Наверняка у этой либы есть метод, который запускает ее обработчик для определенного куска кода (сам не работал с ней, но по схожему принципу работают и другие либы-парсеры).

Это может быть запрос `Intercooler.refresh(eltOrPath)` или `Intercooler.processNodes(elt)` (intercoolerjs.org/docs.html).

По сути, после `Ajax` ты добавляешь новый HTML к существующему в какой-либо контейнер. Потом (желательно если контейнер будет с `id` или хотябы с `class`) этот контейнер ты передаешь на вход этим функциям от интеркулера (т.к. он наследован от JQuery, то можно сразу искать с помощью селекторов типа `".class"`)